# two divs in angular and I need to hide one div and display another when a button in div one is pressed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I have the following code. I need to hide div 1 and display div2 when the button in div one is clicked.  (In ANGULAR HTML5). I have a JS file with controllers etc. at the moement I have two diffetent html template files and I call these as separate modal pop up. Now instead of two pop ups, I need to just show only one pop up but just display or hide content from one of the divs.

```
<div id="div1">
<button name ="click" click="ClickMe()"/>
</div>

<div id = "div2">
<p> Some content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should toggle displayToggled on click, and remove the div from which the button was clicked from the DOM.

```
<div id="div1" ng-if="!displayToggled" >
   <button name ="click" ng-click="displayToggled = true"/>
</div>

<div id = "div2" ng-if="displayToggled">
   <p> Some content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, will try and let you know in sometime

Answer (score 0):

In your html

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl as ctrl">
    <div id="div1" ng-show="ctrl.btn">
        <button name ="click" ng-click="ctrl.btn=!ctrl.btn"/>
    </div>

    <div id = "div2" ng-show="!ctrl.btn">
        <p> Some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

in your controller

```
.controller('myctrl', function(){
    this.btn = true;
 })
```